# x_mat = np.hstack((mat_head, mat_body))

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm getting error in this line x_mat = np.hstack((mat_head, mat_body)) . how wil I resolve it . The error is  all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)

Comment: Tell us more about `mat_head` and `mat_body`, and what kind of result do you want.  `hstack` is most often used to join several 1d arrays into one longer one.  Or some 2d arrays all with the same number of rows.

Comment: mat_head and mat_body are 2D arrays and I want to stack them using hstack but it is giving this error

Comment: that's not what the error tells us.